# Input file with label not updating state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I want to make input type file with custom style, I hide input and styling the label using css. There are 2 problems:

- I chose file, but coverFileState is undefinded (if I remove css style and choose file then everything is okay).
- I want to set file name inside label, but it isn't working. I set text using setCoverUploadText inside handleCoverChange, but no effect.

If you help me with that problem I will really appreciate this, thanks!

---

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    fileInput: {
        marginBottom: '1em',
        width: '0.1px',
        height: '0.1px',
        opacity: '0',
        overflow: "hidden",
        position: "absolute"
    },
    uploadLabel: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        color: "gray",
        border: "1px solid gray"
    }
}));


export default function AddingBook(props: ParamsProps) {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const coverFile = useRef(null);
    const [coverFileState, setCoverFile] = useState<string | Blob>();
    const [coverUploadText, setCoverUploadText] = useState("Upload cover photo *");

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if (coverFileState === undefined) {
            setImageErrorMsg("*Please add cover photo.");
            return;
        }
        api.post('/image/add', JSON.stringify(REST))
            .then(res => {
                uploadCoverPhoto();
                props.close();
            }).catch(err => {
            const errorMsg = APIServices.onError(err);
            showErrorPopup(errorMsg);
        })
    };

    const handleCoverChange = () => {
        // @ts-ignore
        setCoverFile(coverFile.current.files[0]);
        // @ts-ignore
        setCoverUploadText(coverFile.current.files[0].name)
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <input
                    id="copy-file-upload"
                    type="file"
                    accept="image/*"
                    ref={coverFile}
                    onChange={handleCoverChange}
                    data-testid="inputFile"
                    className={classes.fileInput}
                />
                <label className={classes.uploadLabel} htmlFor="copy-file-upload">{coverUploadText}</label>
            </div>
        </>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace "className" by "style" for the input file and for the label.
Hope it will helps you

**EDIT:**
it worked for me when i set the style as :

```
const useStyles = {
    fileInput: {
        marginBottom: '1em',
        width: '0.1px',
        height: '0.1px',
        opacity: '0',
        overflow: "hidden",
        position: "absolute"
    },
    uploadLabel: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        color: "gray",
        border: "1px solid gray"
    }
};
```

and use it in the return as :

```
....
<label style={useStyles.uploadLabel} htmlFor="copy-file-upload">{coverUploadText}</label>
....
```